# "Failed to pipe. The response has been emitted already" when reading a stream (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, readable, fast-csv, node.js-got

So my code is supposed to read some lines from a CSV file, convert them to an array of JSON objects, and return that array.
To read the file as a stream, I am using `got`, and then using it in `fast-csv`.
In order to return the resulting array, I put the entire thing into a Promise like this:

```
async GetPage() : Promise<{OutputArray:any[], StartingIndex:number}>{
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const output:any[] = []; 
            const startingIndex = this.currentLocation;
            try{
                parseStream(this.source, {headers:true, maxRows:this.maxArrayLength, skipRows:this.currentLocation, ignoreEmpty:true, delimiter:this.delimiter})
                    .on('error', error => console.log(`parseStream: ${error}`))
                    .on('data', row => {
                        const obj = this.unflatten(row); // data is flattened JSON, need to unflatten it
                        output.push(obj); // append to output array
                        this.currentLocation++;
                    })
                    .on('end', (rowCount: number) => {
                        console.log(`Parsed ${this.currentLocation} rows`);
                        resolve({OutputArray:output, StartingIndex:startingIndex});
                    });
            }
            catch(ex){
                console.log(`parseStream: ${ex}`);
                throw new Error(ex);
            }
        })
    }
```

Now when I call this once (`await GetPage()`) it works perfectly fine.
The problem is when I'm calling it a second time in a row. I'm getting the following:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to pipe. The response has been emitted already.
```

I've seen a similar case over here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/issues/342 but from what I gather this is a different case, or rather if it's the same I don't know how to apply the solution here.

The `GetPage` is a method inside a class `CSVStreamParser` which is given a `Readable` in the constructor, and I create that Readable like this: `readable:Readable = got.stream(url)`

What confuses me is that my first version of GetPage did not include a Promise, but rather accepted a callback (I just sent `console.log` to test it) and when I called it several times in a row there was no error, but it could not return a value so I converted it to a Promise.

Thank you! :)

EDIT: I have managed to make it work by re-opening the stream at the start of `GetPage()`, but I am wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result without having to do so? Is there a way to keep the stream open?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove both of the `async`, since you are already returning a `Promise`.

Then remove the `try/catch` block and `throw` since you shouldn't throw in a promise. Instead use the `reject` function.

```js
GetPage() : Promise<{OutputArray:any[], StartingIndex:number}>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const output:any[] = []; 
        const startingIndex = this.currentLocation;
        parseStream(this.source, {headers:true, maxRows:this.maxArrayLength, skipRows:this.currentLocation, ignoreEmpty:true, delimiter:this.delimiter})
            .on('error', error => reject(error))
            .on('data', row => {
                const obj = this.unflatten(row); // data is flattened JSON, need to unflatten it
                output.push(obj); // append to output array
                this.currentLocation++;
            })
            .on('end', (rowCount: number) => {
                console.log(`Parsed ${this.currentLocation} rows`);
                resolve({OutputArray:output, StartingIndex:startingIndex});
            });
    });
}
```

Here's some resources to help you learn about [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment!
I did cut some of the code out since I thought it was irrelevant for the question, but inside the  method I am awaiting for an async function, which is why I declared the method as async.
The problem is that even after applying your suggestion, the same thing happens. "Failed to pipe. The response has been emitted already."

Comment: I think "got" closes the stream but I'm not sure exactly where, when, and how to stop it from doing so